# How to capture user comments in watson conversation where we cant define intent

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

Iam working on small flow in watson conversation.Currently I want to capture the comments given by the user,but Iam not sure what would be the intent or entity to be used if any in this case.

To be more clear,

```
1.In one dialog node,watson will give some data and ask to provide comments if required
2..If yes .It will ask for comments .Then user will provide some
3.On enter it should go to Thankyou node where it will display some acknowledgement 
and jump back to main branch node.

Issue for me here is:
On which condition can I go to Thankyou node after user gives his comment since I cant 
give any intent or entity.
```

[image]

Can someone help me with any ideas

Answer (score 2):

If you wish your thanks you node to always execute, and say thanks for our feedback etc, then the easiest condition to add is simply "true" so just add the word true into the trigger / condition element, and the node will always be executed. This is also a great condition to add to any conversation flow as the last default node.